# Getting the number in the ones place python3

Tags: python-3.x, math

I was wondering if there was any way to get the ones place of a integer. For example, if I had the number 41, would there be any easy way to get 1 from that? Thanks!

Comment: Take the number modulo 10.

Comment: `ones = number % 10`. With negative numbers you might want to convert to absolute value first: `ones = abs(number) %10`

Answer (score 0):

Take modulo by 10

```
 a = float(input('Enter a number : '))
 print( a % 10)
```

Modulo operator return the remainder of number so any number modulo with 10 will return its ones number for more https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

Comment: What if I enter -12.2761?

Comment: It will break :(